# How to solve "package is not in GOROOT" when using `go build`?

Tags: go

I have the following simple project architecture:

```
LICENSE     Makefile    README.md   cmd     docs
```

with a `test/main.go` inside of the `cmd` directory (since I want to build a CLI tool).
My Makefile contains:

```
test:
    gofmt -s -w cmd/test/
    go build cmd/test/ -o test
```

The first command `gofmt` works properly but `go build` causes an error

```
package cmd/test is not in GOROOT
```

What's the correct way to compile?

Comment: I'd recommend you check out [Getting started](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started) and [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code) to better understand how to properly structure your Go project.

Comment: I'll do some research, thank you for the hint

Comment: I have already read the links you added to your answer but I don't find an answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to make it work with:

```sh
go build -o ./test ./cmd/test/*.go
```

This is because the [`go build`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies) command takes as its `[packages]` argument a list of *import paths*, or a list of *.go files*.

> `go build [-o output] [build flags] [packages]`
>
> Build compiles the `packages` named by the **import paths**, along with
> their dependencies, but it does not install the results.
>
> If the arguments to build are a **list of .go files from a single
> directory**, build treats them as a list of source files specifying a
> single package.
>
> ...

Your argument `cmd/test/` is neither an import path, nor a list of .go files.

If you want to build a package from its directory's contents you can use `./cmd/test/*.go` and your shell will generally replace that with the list of .go file entries in that directory.

---

Note however that the recommended approach is to utilize go modules. Wiht go modules you can build your package by specifying its import path instead of the directory's contents. For example given a project structure like the following:

```
program
└── cmd
    └── test
        └── test.go
```

you'd `go mod init` from within the root of the project:

```sh
go mod init program
```

that will create a new `go.mod` file for your project:

```
program
├── cmd
│   └── test
│       └── test.go
└── go.mod
```

and then you can build your package using its import path (which is rooted in the module's path), like so for example:

```sh
go build -o ./test program/cmd/test
```

Comment: This does work indeed thank you, I was confused since some answers on this website were indicating `go build .`

Comment: What is the advantage of adding `./`?

Comment: @Victor none that I know of, it's just a habit of mine.